# Read words from file into list

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I've seen many examples online on how to read lines from a file and how to add it to a list. The simplest example was (not my work):

```
List<string> allLinesText = File.ReadAllLines("File.txt").ToList();
```

Issue is, these examples always add a line from .txt files into a list. Can I modify it so that instead of identifying a line in a .txt file, the code instead identifies a word (separated by a space) and adds it to a list while excluding punctuation?

I've been attempting to get it to work for the following data:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla dapibus nibh vitae metus lobortis viverra hendrerit quis ante. Duis non congue tellus. Vestibulum vitae consectetur orci, ut gravida sem.
```

What I'm attempting to do is store each word above into a list or array so that I can attempt to manipulate it later.

Comment: `File.ReadAllText` will give you a single string with the entire file contents. Then you can use `string.Split` to break it up however you want.

Comment: Punctuation can be tricky, so how accurate do the results need to be? What about possessives and numbers and alphanumeric words? For example, what is the expected list of words given a line like: "I was on cloud 9; my life's work was "complete", so to speak, so I settled down to watch the 49ers play." Also, do you have multi-line "lines ? Regular expressions may end up being the way to go...

Comment: Like the sample text shows, only commas and full-stops are a concern. Oh and brackets to be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the entire file into a text string and split it:

```
var allWords = Regex.Split(File.ReadAllText("File.txt"), @"[\s,;:.!?-]+");
```

You may elaborate the regex to allow specific cases such as treating hyphen delimited word as a single one if necessary.

Alternatively, if you may restrict the requirements to a limited list of delimiter characters, use `string.Split()`:

```
var allWords = File.ReadAllText("File.txt")
    .Split(
        new[] { ' ', '\n', '\r', ',', ';', ':', '.', '!', '?', '-' },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
    );
```

Comment: @JimmyK: in this case you'd better find all words with specific conditions using a regex: `var allWords = Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText("File.txt"), @"(?i)\b(?!v)\w+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();`

Comment: Since this comment covers all the OP's requirements, I would edit the answer to include this solution, pointing out how `(?i)` might *or might not* be required. Upvoted though :-)

Comment: Figured out what I was having trouble with after looking more into the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`File.ReadAllText("File.txt")` returns string. Therefore, you can split the string with space {' '}.

You can use

```
 var allLinesText = File.ReadAllText("File.txt").Split(' ').ToList();
```

Comment: Oh I was being silly... I found examples online telling me to use "$" but I didn't realise their data is separated by dollar signs.

Comment: You probably mean `ReadAllText`. Edit: `.ToString()` doesn't convert an array to a string.

Comment: string[].ToString() => System.String[]

Comment: Sorry, it should be ReadAllText()